# Measure of matrices of nullity $1$, among singular ones.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lebesgue-measure, random-matrices, matrix-analysis

We know that for a given measure (Lebesgue, or a probability measure) for the whole set of matrices $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, the set of singular ones are of measure zero. However, let $S_n\subset\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be the set of $n\times n$ singular matrices with real entries. **If we define a nonzero measure for $S_n$ (a new probability measure for example), what can we say about the measure of the matrices with nullity (dimension of kernel) 1? Is it possible to conclude that the set of singular matrices with nullity 1 have measure 1?** (among the singular ones)

I think that this is the case, since the set of matrices of nullity $n$, is just the zero matrix, so this set must be of measure 0. From this point, I don't think it should be different for matrices of nullity e.g. $n-1$: its hard for me to think that the measure distributes nonzero fractions of it between nullity $n-1$, $n-2$, etc... Moreover, if you generate singular random matrices (with normally distributed components, constrained to the $det(M)=0$ condition, for example), you get matrices with nullity 1 most of the times.

One final (bonus) question: Would the answer change, if we restrict to singular and **symmetric** matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

For every $(i,j) \in \lbrace 1, ..., n \rbrace^2$, consider the application $f_{ij} : \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where for every matrix $M \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$, $f_{ij}(M)$ is the value of the determinant of the submatrix obtained by deleting the $i-$th row and the $j-$th column of $M$.

Then the set of matrices that have a nullity of dimension $\geq 2$ is exactly
$$\bigcap_{(i,j) \in \lbrace 1, ..., n \rbrace^2} f_{ij}^{-1}(0)$$

The $f_{ij}$ being polynomial, and the vanishing set of any polynomial having Lebesgue measure zero, you get that the set of matrices that have a nullity of dimension $\geq 2$ has measure zero in the set of matrices that have a nullity of dimension $1$.

Comment: Nice! can you provide more detail on the fact that "the set of matrices that have a nullity of dimension $\geq 2$ is exactly 
$\bigcap_{(i,j) \in \lbrace 1, ..., n \rbrace^2} f_{ij}^{-1}(0)$" or give a reference? This fact is not particularly clear to me.

Comment: @RodrigoAldana Maybe you saw this characterization of the rank : the rank of a matrix $M$ is the largest size of a invertible submatrix of $M$. So you can see that matrices of rank $n-1$ (i.e. of nullity $1$) have an invertible submatrix of size $n-1$, whereas matrices of rank $n-2$ or less (i.e. of nullity $\geq 2$) don't.

Comment: Hey, this makes a lot of sense. Haven't thought about the rank in that way. Thanks sir.

Comment: @RodrigoAldana You are welcome. This characterization of the rank is sometimes useful, for example to show topological properties of the set of matrices of a given rank for example.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, just have another question. How do we know that the the zero set for polinomials $f_{ij}$ was not exacly the zero set of $det(M)$. In that setting the zero set of $f_{ij}$ is of meassure zero, but also the zero set of $det(M)$. Sounds like it cant happen of course (almost for any matrix), but I wonder if there is something Im missing here. Maybe Im saying complete nonsense sorry... Im still trying to get all these ideas.

Comment: @RodrigoAldana Not sure to understand what you mean, but if you take a matrix $M$ of rank $n-1$, then $M$ will *not* belong to $\bigcap_{(i,j) \in \lbrace 1, ..., n \rbrace^2} f_{ij}^{-1}(0)$ (because at least one of its submatrices has to be invertible), whereas $\det(M)=0$.